# Normalize a vector by extending/compressing it to a given length

Tags: r, vector, normalization

I have a vector containing 122 values:

```
vec1 = c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-0.0029,-0.0029,-0.0029,-0.0029,-0.0029,-0.0029,-0.0044,-0.0044,-0.0059,-0.0073,-0.0073,-0.0088,-0.0088,-0.0102,-0.0132,-0.0176,-0.0249,-0.0293,-0.0322,-0.0337,-0.0337,-0.0337,-0.0337,-0.0337,-0.0337,-0.0351,-0.0425,-0.0512,-0.0586,-0.0659,-0.0703,-0.0805,-0.0937,-0.1127,-0.1347,-0.1508,-0.1581,-0.1611,-0.1669,-0.1684,-0.1698,-0.1698,-0.1698,-0.1698,-0.1552,-0.1362,-0.104,-0.0439,0.0747,0.2035,0.3353,0.4583,0.5695,0.6501,0.7277,0.7687,0.7892,0.8038,0.8097,0.8141,0.8184,0.8214,0.8243,0.8243,0.8053,0.7804,0.6603,0.5066,0.3338,0.1435,-0.1127,-0.41,-0.6442,-0.8097,-0.8858,-0.9092,-0.9092,-0.9092,-0.9092,-0.9092,-0.9092,-0.9092,-0.9092,-0.9092,-0.9092,-0.9034,-0.8946,-0.8741,-0.8433,-0.8228,-0.8126,-0.8082,-0.8082,-0.8082,-0.8082,-0.8082,-0.8082,-0.8082,-0.8082,-0.8082,-0.8082,-0.8082,-0.8082,-0.8082,-0.8082,-0.8082,-0.8082,-0.8082,-0.8082,-0.8082,-0.8082,-0.8082,-0.8082,-0.8082)
```

Now I want to normalize it by compressing to 100 values, i.e., in this case, every 1.22 values of vec1 should be represented by 1 value of norm_vec1, like this:

```
norm_vec1 [1] = mean (vec1 [1]) ## (because round(1.22) = 1)
norm_vec1 [2] = mean (vec1 [2]) ## (because round(1.22*2) = 2)
norm_vec1 [3] = mean (vec1 [3:4]) ## (because round(1.22*3) = 4)
norm_vec1 [4] = mean (vec1 [5]) ## (because round(1.22*4) = 5)
```

etc.

As a result, I should get 100 values in the vector norm_vec1, each of those is either directly taken from vec1 or is a result of averaging, depending on its' position. No values from vec1 should be missed.
Importantly, this also should work for vectors shorter than 100 (e.g., 63 elements):

```
norm_short_vec1 [1] = mean (short_vec1 [1]) ## (because round(0.63*1)=1)
norm_short_vec1 [2] = mean (short_vec1 [1]) ## (because round(0.63*2)=1)
norm_short_vec1 [3] = mean (short_vec1 [2]) ## (because round(0.63*3)=2)
```

etc.

Or, alternatively, every vector can be multiplied by 100 and than new values can be based on samples from this new longer vector like this (if vec1 has 122 values):

```
long_vec1 = c(c(vec1 [1] repeated 100 times),  (vec1 [2] repeated 100 times), etc.)
norm_vec1 [1] = mean (long_vec1 [1:122])
norm_vec1 [2] = mean (long_vec1 [123:244])
etc.
```

Is there any function for this?

Comment: Maybe you can create a sequence of values from min to max of vector with fixed length? `seq(min(vec1), max(vec1), length.out = 100)` but this will change your original values in `vec1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
compress <- function(x, length.out) {
  n <- length(x)
  if (n < length.out) stop("length.out is too big")
  spl <- round((1:n)/n*length.out)
  res <- sapply(split(x, spl), mean)
  names(res) <- NULL
  res
}

compress(vec1, 100)
#>   [1]  0.00000  0.00000  0.00000  0.00000  0.00000  0.00000 -0.00145
#>   [8] -0.00290 -0.00290 -0.00290 -0.00290 -0.00440 -0.00440 -0.00590
#>  [15] -0.00730 -0.00805 -0.00880 -0.01020 -0.01320 -0.02125 -0.02930
#>  [22] -0.03220 -0.03370 -0.03370 -0.03370 -0.03370 -0.03370 -0.03510
#>  [29] -0.04250 -0.05490 -0.06590 -0.07030 -0.08050 -0.10320 -0.13470
#>  [36] -0.15080 -0.15810 -0.16110 -0.16765 -0.16980 -0.16980 -0.16980
#>  [43] -0.16250 -0.13620 -0.10400 -0.04390  0.07470  0.26940  0.45830
#>  [50]  0.56950  0.65010  0.74820  0.78920  0.80380  0.80970  0.81410
#>  [57]  0.81990  0.82430  0.82430  0.80530  0.72035  0.50660  0.33380
#>  [64]  0.14350 -0.11270 -0.52710 -0.80970 -0.88580 -0.90920 -0.90920
#>  [71] -0.90920 -0.90920 -0.90920 -0.90920 -0.90920 -0.90920 -0.90340
#>  [78] -0.89460 -0.87410 -0.83305 -0.81260 -0.80820 -0.80820 -0.80820
#>  [85] -0.80820 -0.80820 -0.80820 -0.80820 -0.80820 -0.80820 -0.80820
#>  [92] -0.80820 -0.80820 -0.80820 -0.80820 -0.80820 -0.80820 -0.80820
#>  [99] -0.80820 -0.80820
```

Here `spl` describes connection between elements of the original vector and the resulting vector. In this particular example it consists of 122 values: `1, 2, 2, 3, 4, ... 99, 100`, meaning that first element will go directly to the resulting vector, then second and third will be averaged to populate element 2 of the resulting vector and so on.

**UPD**

A function based on your second algorithm.

```r
normalize <- function(x, length.out) {
  n <- length(x)
  big_vec <- rep(x, each = length.out)
  res <- sapply(split(big_vec, rep(1:length.out, each = n)), mean)
  names(res) <- NULL
  res
}
```

This works in the opposite direction as well:

```r
normalize(1:3, length.out = 5)
#> [1] 1.000000 1.333333 2.000000 2.666667 3.000000
```

Comment: this works well with compressing, but is not able to extend a vector shorter than length.out

Comment: I would actually prefer the second solution too, thanks! But the problem here is the sample function which randomly takes values from the vector. I assume this must be a typo? Your example with 1:3 is distorted too: > normalize(1:3, length.out = 5)
[1] 3.000000 2.000000 1.333333 2.000000 1.666667

Comment: @Alex  Sorry, copied from a wrong place. I’ve updated it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution with `Map`. It is used to create a list of indices into the input vector giving which vector elements to aggregate with `mean`.

```
fun <- function(x, n = 100){
  r <- round(seq_len(n)*length(x)/n)
  d <- c(0, diff(r))
  M <- Map(`:`, (r - d + 1), r)
  sapply(M, function(i) mean(x[i]))
}

fun(vec1)
```

Comment: if I extend a vector shorter than n, I get a NA at the end

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function `compress` with any positive integer `shortlen` for the object length to your compression purpose, where `split` and `findInterval` are applied to produce chunks for averaging:

```
compress <- function(v, shortlen){
   unname(sapply(split(v,findInterval(seq_along(v),round(length(v)/shortlen*seq_along(v)),left.open = T)),mean))
}
```

For example:

```
> compress(vec1,100)
  [1]  0.00000  0.00000  0.00000  0.00000  0.00000  0.00000 -0.00145 -0.00290 -0.00290 -0.00290 -0.00290 -0.00365 -0.00440 -0.00590 -0.00730 -0.00805 -0.00880
 [18] -0.01020 -0.01320 -0.01760 -0.02710 -0.03220 -0.03370 -0.03370 -0.03370 -0.03370 -0.03370 -0.03510 -0.04250 -0.05490 -0.06590 -0.07030 -0.08050 -0.09370
 [35] -0.12370 -0.15080 -0.15810 -0.16110 -0.16765 -0.16980 -0.16980 -0.16980 -0.16980 -0.14570 -0.10400 -0.04390  0.07470  0.26940  0.45830  0.56950  0.65010
 [52]  0.72770  0.77895  0.80380  0.80970  0.81410  0.81990  0.82430  0.82430  0.80530  0.78040  0.58345  0.33380  0.14350 -0.11270 -0.52710 -0.80970 -0.88580
 [69] -0.90920 -0.90920 -0.90920 -0.90920 -0.90920 -0.90920 -0.90920 -0.90920 -0.90340 -0.89460 -0.87410 -0.83305 -0.81260 -0.80820 -0.80820 -0.80820 -0.80820
 [86] -0.80820 -0.80820 -0.80820 -0.80820 -0.80820 -0.80820 -0.80820 -0.80820 -0.80820 -0.80820 -0.80820 -0.80820 -0.80820 -0.80820 -0.80820
> compress(vec1,63)
 [1]  0.00000  0.00000  0.00000  0.00000 -0.00290 -0.00290 -0.00290 -0.00440 -0.00515 -0.00730 -0.00880 -0.01170 -0.02125 -0.03075 -0.03370 -0.03370 -0.03370
[18] -0.03880 -0.05490 -0.06810 -0.08710 -0.12370 -0.15445 -0.16110 -0.16765 -0.16980 -0.16980 -0.14570 -0.07395  0.13910  0.39680  0.60980  0.74820  0.79650
[35]  0.81190  0.81990  0.82430  0.79285  0.58345  0.33380  0.01540 -0.52710 -0.84775 -0.90920 -0.90920 -0.90920 -0.90920 -0.90920 -0.89900 -0.85870 -0.81770
[52] -0.80820 -0.80820 -0.80820 -0.80820 -0.80820 -0.80820 -0.80820 -0.80820 -0.80820 -0.80820 -0.80820 -0.80820
```

Answer (score 0):

Interesting problem. Here is one option:

```
alex_normalize <- function(vec, tol = 100) {
    k <- length(vec) / tol
    from <- round(k * seq_len(tol))
    sapply(
      seq_len(tol), 
      function(i) mean(vec[seq(max(from[i-1L], 1L), from[i])])
    )
}

alex_normalize(vec1)

  [1]  0.0000000000  0.0000000000  0.0000000000  0.0000000000  0.0000000000  0.0000000000
  [7] -0.0009666667 -0.0029000000 -0.0029000000 -0.0029000000 -0.0029000000 -0.0034000000
 [13] -0.0044000000 -0.0051500000 -0.0066000000 -0.0078000000 -0.0088000000 -0.0095000000
 [19] -0.0117000000 -0.0154000000 -0.0239333333 -0.0307500000 -0.0329500000 -0.0337000000
 [25] -0.0337000000 -0.0337000000 -0.0337000000 -0.0344000000 -0.0388000000 -0.0507666667
 [31] -0.0622500000 -0.0681000000 -0.0754000000 -0.0871000000 -0.1137000000 -0.1427500000
 [37] -0.1544500000 -0.1596000000 -0.1654666667 -0.1691000000 -0.1698000000 -0.1698000000
 [43] -0.1698000000 -0.1537333333 -0.1201000000 -0.0739500000  0.0154000000  0.2045000000
 [49]  0.3968000000  0.5139000000  0.6098000000  0.6889000000  0.7618666667  0.7965000000
 [55]  0.8067500000  0.8119000000  0.8179666667  0.8228500000  0.8243000000  0.8148000000
 [61]  0.7928500000  0.6491000000  0.4202000000  0.2386500000  0.0154000000 -0.3889666667
 [67] -0.7269500000 -0.8477500000 -0.8975000000 -0.9092000000 -0.9092000000 -0.9092000000
 [73] -0.9092000000 -0.9092000000 -0.9092000000 -0.9092000000 -0.9063000000 -0.8990000000
 [79] -0.8843500000 -0.8467333333 -0.8177000000 -0.8104000000 -0.8082000000 -0.8082000000
 [85] -0.8082000000 -0.8082000000 -0.8082000000 -0.8082000000 -0.8082000000 -0.8082000000
 [91] -0.8082000000 -0.8082000000 -0.8082000000 -0.8082000000 -0.8082000000 -0.8082000000
 [97] -0.8082000000 -0.8082000000 -0.8082000000 -0.8082000000
```